# System contracts vs solidity contracts

Tags: solidity, blockchain, contract-deployment

How to convert a solidity smart contract into a system contract? It would be for an Ethereum Fork, we want to implement a smart contract as a system contract.

Also would it be possible to update the source code of the bloclchain so that we can "update" the smart contract bytecode like hard forks but keep the storage data of the contract?

Lastely we already have a smart contract deployed with solidity, we would like to keep the address of the smart contract and its data storage but update the bytecode with few edits in the original smart contract code. I imagine something like EIPs where the new smart contract would be activated only after a certain block height.

I was told it's possible to create system smart contract by putting smart contract code in go in this function:https://github.com/etclabscore/core-geth/blob/master/core/vm/contracts.go#L124

If you know how it works, could you give further explanation and how we can transform solidity smart contract into system smart contract

Thank you very much for help!